# How do get a list of pages by Location in the Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-runtime, winjs

I would like to get a list of pages by Location, preferably Lat and Long, from the Facebook Open Graph. The Location object is not indexed, understandably, so FQL can't seem to get it.  Has anyone managed to get a list of pages any other way?

This is for a Windows 8 Metro app in HTML5, in case technology matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this fairly easy with an access token, just use Graph API Searching:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching

For example, you could make this call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=*&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=TOKEN`